# truncate date to week and compare against existing variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column called Actuals_Date and I want to insert dates into a table on a rolling basis such that the previous 6 weeks and next 8 weeks are loaded into the table.

For the previous 6 weeks, I have the following sql structure (from Tableau)

```
[Actuals Date] > DATEADD('week',-6,DATETRUNC('week', TODAY()) - 1) and [Actuals Date] <= DATETRUNC('week', TODAY()) - 1
```

and for the next 8 weeks, following syntax from Tableau:

```
[Forecast Date] >= DATETRUNC('week', TODAY()) - 1  
and [Forecast Date] <= DATEADD('week', 7,DATETRUNC('week', TODAY()) - 1)
```

can someone please help me convert this into a sql query?

Comment: Not sure I understand... but Given a Date variable you want the query to generate +/- n weeks of dates ?

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish your goal would be to use [DATEADD()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

**Previous 6 Weeks:**

```
SELECT f.MyColumns
FROM dbo.MyTable f
WHERE f.MyDateField BETWEEN DATEADD(WEEK,-6,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AND CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

**Next 8 Weeks:**

```
SELECT f.MyColumns
FROM dbo.MyTable f
WHERE f.MyDateField BETWEEN CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND DATEADD(WEEK,8,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

Note:  This assumes that f.MyDateField is a date without time.  If f.MyDateField has a time, you will want to CAST it as DATE

```
SELECT f.MyColumns
FROM dbo.MyTable f
WHERE CAST(f.MyDateField AS DATE) BETWEEN DATEADD(WEEK,-6,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AND CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```